# paper-dialog hero animation

Tags: javascript, animation, polymer-1.0

I have a standard `paper-toolbar` with a settings button that launches a dialog. Everything works as expected. I would like to scale animate the dialog starting from/to the button instead of center of the screen. Not sure how to make use of hero animation to get the behavior ? Appreciate any help on this.

```
<paper-toolbar>
<span class="title">Heading</span>
<paper-button on-click="showDialog">Settings<iron-icon icon="settings" style="margin-left:5px"></iron-icon></paper-button>
</paper-toolbar>


<paper-dialog id="dialog" modal entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="scale-down-animation">

showDialog: function () {
                var dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
                if (dialog) {
                    dialog.open();
                }
            }
```